# ExtJS 6.7 Modern - Ext.grid.Tree selectOnExpander doesnt work on node load

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm using ExtJS 6.7 Modern toolkit and [Ext.grid.Tree.selectOnExpander](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html#cfg-selectOnExpander) = false does not work properly when data for expandable node is loading from a remote server, i.e. node is selected when I click on the expander.

I expect that in this case the node will NOT be selected as in the case when the data is already loaded.

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31u0) as an illustration - try to expand node when it is loaded and when it is not loaded yet using expander.

---

So far I've tried to check fired events with [Ext.util.Observable.capture](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.util.Observable.html#static-method-capture) and it seems like extra [`childtap`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.dataview.Component.html#event-childtap) event is triggired. I don't yet understand why. Seems like a bug for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems they forgot to implement the logic.

From the code I would sugget to use this snippet.
It extens the logic from `Ext.dataview.List` using the same style.

Sencha Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31va)

```
Ext.define('Portal.grid.Tree', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.Tree',

    shouldSelectItem: function(e) {
        var me = this,
            no = !me.callParent([e]),
            cmp;

        if (!no && !me.selectOnExpander) {
            cmp = e.getTarget();
            no = cmp.classList.contains('x-expander-el');
        }

        return !no;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far is to override [Ext.grid.Tree](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html) `onChildTap` method (inherited from [Ext.dataview.Abstract](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.dataview.Abstract.html)) like this:

```
Ext.define('Portal.grid.Tree', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.Tree',

    /** Override Ext.dataview.Abstract onChildTap method for correct processing selectOnExpander property **/
    onChildTap: function(location) {
        if (this.getSelectOnExpander() || location.event.target !== location.cell.expanderElement.dom) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    },
});
```